# Set notation that apparently describes prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set given to me was this

$B = \{x \in \mathbb{N} |  \ \   x \; mod \  y = 0 \Rightarrow y = 1 \ or \ y = x, x > 1, y \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I just couldn't wrap my head around as to why this set describes a set of prime numbers.

Anybody could explain this in further detail?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The conditions tell us that any (positive) divisor of $x>1$ must be either $1$ or $x$, which is the definition of a prime.

Comment: It should have a quantifier "$\forall y\in\mathbb{N}$"  enclosing the entire conditional.

Answer (score 0):

"If natural number $x > 1$ is divisible by a natural number $y$, then $y$ is either equal to $1$ or equal to $x$."

Answer (score 0):

$x \mod y = 0$ means that $y$ divides $x$. So this is the set of all numbers $x > 1$ such that the only numbers $y$ that divide $x$ are $y=1$ and $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

It says that a natural number $x$ (presumably natural numbers start at 1 in this text) is prime if (1) it's greater than $1$, and (2) whenever it's divisible by a natural number $y$, then either $y$ is $1$ OR $y$ is $x$.

Since the definition of "$x$ is prime" is that it's a natural number greater than $1$ that divisible only by $1$ and itself, that's the same thing.

The only tricky thing here is remembering that $x \bmod y = 0$ means that $y$ divides evenly into $x$ (i.e., $y$ is a factor of $x$, or $x$ is divisible by $y$).